# By how much can I trim back the connectors of 1.5" PVC fittings?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, bathtub, drain-waste-vent, fitting

We're installing the drain plumbing for a newly installed tub, and the drain shoe overshoots the tub drain hole. The tub has been mortared in place and can no longer be moved:

[image: Tub drain shoe installed in tight space]

A joist limits how far back the overflow tee can be positioned, and as you can see in the picture, the connectors of the shoe and the tee are already flush against each other.

I only need the shoe drain to move about 1/2" towards the joist. Would it be acceptable to simply trim the connectors of the shoe and tee by 1/4" each to get everything to move back to where I need it?

For reference, the standard depth of the connectors on 1.5" PVC fittings is 3/4". Is there a minimum connection depth that I need to keep to ensure a leakproof connection?

Comment: Have you looked into a street 90 elbow drain fitting.May fit or be to short. Should be able to  move.

Comment: So the tub shoe is actually an application-specific fitting, rather than a standard 90 elbow. But that's a good point, maybe they make a street version of that fitting too!

Comment: They may. And can not see why you could not shorten a street  fitting

Comment: I would use my chop saw to (carefully) trim 1/4" from both solvent-weld sockets. This is not a pressure application, it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the tee in your drain pipe is already cemented in place, but if you can redo it, you can do what they did in my house (not home right now, so I'll have to remember to get a picture later).

What you can do is turn the tee and drain fitting to the sides and use two elbows and three short pipes to connect them.

The only tool I have to illustrate this right now is MS Paint, but it should be better than nothing. This is the view looking down from the top (or up from the bottom):

[image: birds eye view]